# To many rerenders in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
When I put these lines then it shows the errors to many rerenders. I have wrapped onClick and onSubmit functions in arrow function, even then it is showing the error.

```
if(fields){
     setFormFields({
       company: !loading && !fields.company ? "" : fields.company,
     })
   }
```

These lines are mentioned in the code just below useEffect.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Title from "../Title";
import { Container, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { createProfile, getProfile } from "../../redux/profile/ProfileAction";
import { connect, useSelector } from "react-redux";

const EditProfile = ({
  createProfile,
  getProfile,
  profile: { loading, fields },
}) => {
  const style = {
    color: "#1e5799",
    fontWeight: "600",
    fontSize: "3rem",
  };

  const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState({
    status: "",
    company: "",
    website: "",
    location: "",
    skills: "",
    bio: "",
    githubusername: "",
  });

  const {
    status,
    company,
    website,
    location,
    skills,
    bio,
    githubusername,
  } = formFields;

  useEffect(() => {
    getProfile();
  }, [])
  // When I remove comment lines from below then it shows the error.
  // if(fields){
  //   setFormFields({
  //     company: !loading && !fields.company ? "" : fields.company,
  //   })
  // }

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setFormFields({ ...formFields, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createProfile({
      status,
      company,
      website,
      location,
      skills,
      bio,
      githubusername,
    });
  };
  return (
    <section className="edit-profile-section">
      <Container>
        <Title style={style} title="Create Your Profile" />
        <h3>Let's get some information to make your profile stand out</h3>
        <Form onSubmit={e=>onSubmit(e)}>
          <Form.Group controlId="status">
            <Form.Control
              value={status}
              onChange={e=>onChange(e)}
              name="status"
              as="select"
            >
              <option value="engineer">Engineer</option>
              <option value="manager">Manager</option>
              <option value="developer">Developer</option>
              <option value="analyst">Analyst</option>
              <option value="student">Student</option>
              <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
            </Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="company">
            <Form.Control
              value={company}
              onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
              type="text"
              name="company"
              placeholder="Enter company"
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="website">
            <Form.Control
              value={website}
              onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
              type="text"
              name="website"
              placeholder="Enter website"
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="location">
            <Form.Control
              value={location}
              onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
              type="text"
              name="location"
              placeholder="Enter location"
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="skills">
            <Form.Control
              value={skills}
              onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
              type="text"
              name="skills"
              placeholder="Enter skills"
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="githubusername">
            <Form.Control
              value={githubusername}
              onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
              type="text"
              name="githubusername"
              placeholder="Enter githubusername"
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="bio">
            <Form.Control
              value={bio}
              onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
              type="text"
              name="bio"
              placeholder="Enter bio"
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <button className="body-button" onClick={e=>onSubmit(e)}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    </section>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  profile: state.profile,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { createProfile, getProfile })(
  EditProfile
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error makes sense: you are setting the state (by calling `setFormFields`) every time the component re-renders, which in itself causes a re-render which causes an infinite loop.